# ADAL python support for windows logged in user

Tags: azure, adal

We are currently using the adal python library, and wanted to know if there is any way (or plans of implementing a way) to use the signed in user (windows) for a federated authentication flow.

Such a flow is possible using .Net package [link](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/AcquireTokenSilentAsync-using-Integrated-authentication-on-Windows-(Kerberos))

The end goal would be, instead of `acquire_token_with_username_password`, maybe something like `acquire_token_with_signed_in_user`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your research effort on this valuable question (upvoted)!

It is true that neither ADAL Python nor its cousin [MSAL Python](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python) supports "picking up windows signed-in user and use it". That feature is known as [IWA, traditionally only available in our .Net/C# SDK on Windows platforms](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/AcquireTokenSilentAsync-using-Integrated-authentication-on-Windows-(Kerberos)). It is theoretically possible to add that into Python too. We don't currently have it in our roadmap, largely because no one asks for it before. In that sense, feel free to go ahead and [create an issue for it in our MSAL Python github repo](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/issues/new) (and [you did](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/issues/31)), so that people in the world (or your spouse) can upvote it, and then we will [sort them by +1 votes](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+sort%3Areactions-%2B1-desc) when we do our future rounds of planning.

On the other hand, there is already a [token cache behavior in ADAL Python](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python/blob/1.2.1/adal/authentication_context.py#L63-L68) and [in MSAL Python](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python#usage). If you utilize it, and also build your own persistence layer on top of it ([which is very easy in MSAL Python](https://msal-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#msal.SerializableTokenCache)), you can cache the tokens so that you end user would not need to authenticate every time. PS: There is some ongoing effort on providing an even higher level helper for token cache persistence, but that is a different topic.

<sup>Also thanks @mohitdhingra-msft for providing another answer here which is also correct.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You are able to get an accessToken and refreshToken by using **acquire_token_with_username_password** method. As per the below documentations, there is no such method for acquiring the token with signed in user but you can use **acquire_token_with_refresh_token** to get a new access token by using the refresh token that you got in the first call. You can use TokenCache class to cache accessToken and refreshToken.

[Refresh Token in adal python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/adal/adal.authentication_context.authenticationcontext?view=azure-python#acquire-token-with-refresh-token-refresh-token--client-id--resource--client-secret-none-) and 
https://adal-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

I hope this helps.